# Decimal Database to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, json

I have Decimal data type in my database with value 0.00 but in JSON result is .00, How I can convert so i can still get 0.00 in result ?

I working in Jquery.. Thanks

This my code

```
<?php 
include "../../../config/config.php";
$kd_entitas=$_POST['kd_entitas'];
$tglAwal = $_POST['tglAwal'];
$tglAkhir = $_POST['tglAkhir'];
$con = sqlsrv_connect(serverNameAST,$connectionInfoAST) or die('Unable to Connect');
if( $con === false )
{
echo "Could not connect.\n";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else{
    //$sql = "SELECT SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan, t.* FROM SYS_DEPT t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r";
    $sql="[Daily_report_r] '$kd_entitas','$kd_entitas','$tglAwal','$tglAkhir'";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
        $data = array();
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }


        $datax = array('data' => $data);
        echo json_encode($datax);
}
?>
```

[Result JSON in field oustand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEa5g.png)

[Result from my database sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqGWb.png)

Comment: `but in JSON result is .00` - so, it's a string. the server side code (which you haven't shown) will need to be fixed - note, it'll still be a string value

Comment: Could you show your server side code?

Comment: Also, how are you creating the JSON? Are you using native functions for that? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I using SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1. When you're getting the data from database all values will be strings. If you want a specific number to be a double then you have to explicitly cast it to a double.
2. If you want to preserve zero fraction in json you have to use `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` flag in `json_encode`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php for details.

But this solution will preserve only one zero and will only work on numbers of type double. If you want to have more zeros after coma you have to leave the number in the string and handle yourself.

If the number from the database is returned without the fraction part then check your field type or field precision.